# No data is available for encoding 936

Tags: ios, xamarin, codepages

I’m working on program that use Thermal printer to print invoice from mobile app, it works just fine in English, but when I try to print Chinese words, it shows following error, could someone kindly advise how to resolve it?

error message : No data is available for encoding 936.

```
private byte[] UTF8Encoding (string myString) {
Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

myString = "披";
byte[] unicodeBytes = null;
byte[] asciiBytes = null;
try {
unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(myString);
asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312"), unicodeBytes);
} catch (Exception e) {
Debug.Log ("{0}", e.Message);
}
//          myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
return unicodeBytes;
}
```

I also tried to add the Microsoft Codepage component, but it shows following error and can’t allow me adding it into Xamarin project:

Adding System.Text.Encoding.CodePages...
The 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.7.0’.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly include the codepage within the iOS build options:

[image]

Since you are missing code page 936, include `cjk` in your build options. Ensure you do this for all build configurations (Debug, Release etc).

See:

- [IOS - Localisation and Internationalization](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/encodings/)